# Default behaviour of LDAP connection without LDAP URL

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

This is how I created DirectoryEntry to connect to AD server(13.198.123.456)

```
DirectoryEntry ldap_connection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://13.198.123.456/OU=Abc,DC=def,DC=ijk,DC=com", "username", "password");
```

But if I created DirectoryEntry without LDAP URL, It will connect to the AD that uses to logging to my PC

```
DirectoryEntry ldap_connection = new DirectoryEntry("", "username", "password");
```

Is this expected behavior? any documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly clear, but the version you use is another case of the default `DirectoryEntry` constructor, but with non-default credentials - as [illustrated on this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180841%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), when you use:

```
DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry();
```

it indicates that you bind to the domain that provides authentication for the user.

In the case of:

```
DirectoryEntry ldap_connection = new DirectoryEntry("", "username", "password");
```

The empty string implies that you bind to the domain that provides authentication to the *logged in* user, but using alternate credentials for the username and password.

I don't have a windows system to hand to test the difference, if any, between passing in an empty string `""`, as opposed to a `null` reference - it may barf in this situation.